# write sql query in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I have a problem in writing sql query in zend framework model.

I want to write native sql query in zend framework models.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats urs req. and what hav u tried?

Answer (score 3):

To expand Bryan's answer :)

First, you have to create a "database adapter" what connects to your database. Each supported database engine has a specific adapter class. The database engine could be MySQL, PostgreSQL..etc
you can find all here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html

For example you can create a MySQL specific adapter like this:

```
$dbAdapter = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxx',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

Then if you have a native SQL query, like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id > 23";
```

then you can use the above `$dbAdapter` object to run this native query, using its `query()` function:

```
$statement = $dbAdapter->query($sql);
```

Now the $statement variable will be a [Zend_Db_Statement](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.statement.html) object. If you want to see the result of this query you can use the `fetch()` function, like:

```
while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
    echo $row['username'];
}
```

While its easy to use, its not the best technique to use the above query() method because
it not helps to promote database-independent queries.
To write database independent queries you  can use `Zend_Db_Select`. But of course, sometimes its not avoidable to use native queries.   You can find here an example how can you write these queries for more db engines:
[Zend_Db_Select order by random, compatible in mssql / mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474365/zend-db-select-order-by-random-compatible-in-mssql-mysql)

Based on this example you can use different queries based on your adapter's type..